# Mahapps TextBox style missing after chnage Backgroud color via code behind

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles, mahapps.metro

So this is my `TextBox` style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1,0,0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0052B2"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF103766"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF7AA0CD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My controller:

```
<TextBox
    Name="Filter"
    Width="398"
    Height="25"
    TextChanged="tbSnifferFilter_TextChanged"                                    
    Margin="23,0,0,0"/>
```

In my application the user need to type inside my `TextBox` filter (simple string), and via the following method i am checking if this filter is valid or not and change my `TextBox` `Backgroud` color to `Green` or `Red`:

```
private void tbFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tbFilter.TextChanged -= tbFilter_TextChanged;

    if (tbFilter.Text == "") // In case user click on clear button - return back to default backgroud color.
    {
        tbFilter.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FF103766");
        tbFilter.TextChanged += tbFilter_TextChanged;
        return;
    }

    if (!IsSyntaxCurrect(tbFilter.Text))
        tbFilter.Background = Brushes.Salmon;
    else
        tbFilter.Background = Brushes.MediumSeaGreen;

    tbFilter.TextChanged += tbFilter_TextChanged;
}

private bool IsSyntaxCurrect(string filter)
{
    try
    {
        // Do my stuff...
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So after add filter (valid ot not valid) and after that user click on `TextBox` clear button to clean the `TextBox` the `Background` color return to the default color but `Mouse Over` not working and do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the local `Background` value that you set in the event handler takes precedence over the value set by your `Style`. Please refer to MSDN for more information about dependency property value precedence: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx

Instead of setting the `Background` property to a new `Brush` value when the `TextBox` is cleared, you could clear the value of the dependency property using the `ClearValue` method:

```
private void tbFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tbFilter.TextChanged -= tbFilter_TextChanged;

    if (tbFilter.Text == "") // In case user click on clear button - return back to default backgroud color.
    {
        tbFilter.ClearValue(TextBox.BackgroundProperty); //<-- 
        tbFilter.TextChanged += tbFilter_TextChanged;
        return;
    }

    if (!IsSyntaxCurrect(tbFilter.Text))
        tbFilter.Background = Brushes.Salmon;
    else
        tbFilter.Background = Brushes.MediumSeaGreen;

    tbFilter.TextChanged += tbFilter_TextChanged;
}
```